# How to synchronise two QGraphicsViews?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a simple *gui* that has two *QGraphicsViews* in it. Once you run the app it loads an image and displays it in both views. You can then go on and choose some simple operations and press a button to see them have effect only on the image in the right.

What I thought would be nice is to be able while panning on zooming on one of the images, the other one to follow up. So if you want to focus on a particular area on one image, the exact same will happen on the other one too.

I can not see how I can get the information on what exactly I am looking at in one of the GraphicsViews so as to synchronise the other though.

Is this possible, and if yes how would I go on about doing it?

**Edit1**
There has been some progress, but yet there are a few problems remaining.
What I decided to do is take the viewport geometry relative to the scene.

```
QRectF viewport5 = m_workspace1->mapToScene(m_workspace1->viewport()->geometry()).boundingRect();
```

and then try and set it as the geometry for the viewport of the other scene

```
m_workspace2->viewport()->setGeometry(viewport5.toRect());
```

but this creates an effect where the second image moves to a direction opposite to the one I am moving the first picture. The one it is supposed to be following. Moreover it moves the second image to the corner of the QGraphicsView as can be seen below. Note that when I try to resize the window, and only while I am resizing it the image returns at the middle as it is supposed to.

[image]

**Edit2**
Te issues get fixed if you use

```
m_workspace2->setSceneRect(viewport5);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be not all that hard.

Use

```
QRectF viewport1 = m_workspace1->mapToScene(m_workspace1->viewport()->geometry()).boundingRect();
```

to get a rectangle that shows you what part of your scene is currently visible.

Then simply update the scene in your second view

```
m_workspace2->setSceneRect(viewport1);
```

This can happen every time you move one of the images, or zoom in, by intercepting mouse events, or if you don't care all that much then just subclass QGraphicsView and use 'paintEvent' to emit a signal every time one of your images gets repainted.

Comment: interesting solution so you just repeat the scene rectangle changes from one view to the other.. I wonder if there is some signal of QGraphicsView which will emit when bounding rect of view is changed.. but maybe call it in paintEvent is sufficient enough. You can mark your own question as correct one..

Comment: @otopolsky I did search in the docs and it seems that there is no such signal to emit. But one alternative could be detecting an image drag event, something again not that hard (LMB must be pressed above the widget and mouse must be moving).

Answer (score 0):

I think getting the viewport from first view and then passing it to the next view would do the trick.

```
QWidget *viewport1 = view1->viewport();
view2->setViewport(viewport1);
```

Comment: Indeed, or maybe using **CenterOn**. But how do I know when the viewport changes, is there some signal?

Comment: I just tried setting the viewport in Chips example and it is not working for some reason.. Maybe you can reimplement viewportEvent function or some of these paintEvent(), mousePressEvent(), mouseReleaseEvent(), mouseDoubleClickEvent(), mouseMoveEvent(), wheelEvent(), dragEnterEvent(), dragMoveEvent(), dragLeaveEvent(), dropEvent(), contextMenuEvent(), resizeEvent()

Comment: That is what came in to my mind. I'll try doing that and see how it goes.